# What is the proper way to animate a door?

Tags: animation

I have two objects, a door frame, and a door.  I have the origin in a specific place that it needs to stay at which is not the center of the door, for tiling purposes in Unity.

I move the origin to the lower corner of the door, save frame, rotate 90 on the z, save frame.  When I play the animation it works until I have to move the origin back to the spot where it has to be for tiling purposes, and then it messes it up.  How can I accomplish it so that I can keep my origin in the place I need it, but still have a pivot point?

Comment: Make use of relations and empties. Use an external object like an empty to control rotation pivot, parent all objects to the empty.

Comment: Or use a bone to control the rotation